# How to take data information by id and view in my update form input

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label><?=lang('Students')?></label><br>
    <select name="students[]" id="students" class="form-control input-large select2" multiple>
       <?foreach($students as $student):?>
         <option value="<?=$student->student_id?>"><?=$student->student_surname.' '.$student->student_name.' '.$student->student_middlename?></option>
       <?endforeach?>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Problem is** to view all data in multiple select input so user can edit. Now multiple select is empty and user should select again

Comment: Attribute "value" not allowed on element "select"

Comment: ok, I understand that, the main problem is to view information

Comment: does your select box fill up properly? Why it's empty?

Comment: yeap, it fill up properly multiple select box connected to my database. And question is how to view previously entered data.

Comment: do you mean "previously selected items" after submit?

Comment: Post your complete code. As well as have to say ***Unclear what you asking.***

Comment: @RavshanAbdurasulov  how are you storing the previously entered data of select box??

Answer (score 1):

Is this is what you are asking- To display the multiple selected items when you edit?

View-

```
   <div class="form-group public-cus-form-field-wrap">
    <label for="treatment" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Treatment</label>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select name="treatment[]" id="treatment" class="col-sm-12 country" style="height: 40px;" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
           <?php
            if ($record->service_treatment)
            {

             $treat = explode(',',$record->service_treatment);
   //$record->service_treatment holds my selected values saved in db
             foreach($treatment as $treatments) // $treatment array holds the values to be displayed in select box
            { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $treatments->treatment_name ?>" <?php if(in_array($treatments->treatment_name, $treat)){echo 'selected="selected"';}?> 
    ><?php echo $treatments->treatment_name; ?></option>
             <?php }  }
           else {  foreach($treatment as $treatments) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $treatments->treatment_name ?>"><?php echo $treatments->treatment_name; ?></option>
         <?php }     }    ?>            
    </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Model-

```
public function name()
{
 if (is_array($this->input->post('treatment')))
    {
      $treatment = implode(",", $this->input->post('treatment'));
    }
    elseif($this->input->post('treatment')){

     $treatment = $this->input->post('treatment');
    }
// $treatment holds the multiple selected values
}
```

Comment: yeap, I used another method but I think results will be same
<option value="<?=$groups_student->student_id?>" selected><?=$groups_student->student_surname.' '.$groups_student->student_name.' '.$groups_student->student_middlename?></option>